# Metodo Object.values( ) não funciona no internet explorer 9

Tags: javascript

Pessoal estou com um problema. Em um arquivo javascript que utilizamos funciona normalmente o metodo Object.values() que pega um objeto e retorna um array. Mas no internet explore 9 não funciona. Alguem poderia ajudar?

exemplo de codigo:

```
var json = '{"6":{"dataInicio":"02\/01\/2017","dataFim":"08\/02\/2017","bonus":"10","idProd":6}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var array = Object.values(obj);
```

No ie mostra o seguinte erro :
SCRIPT438: O objeto não oferece suporte à propriedade ou método 'values'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse método não funciona em alguns navegadores.

Tente: `var array = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){ return obj[key];});`

Comment: Valeu funcionou no ie 9

Answer (score 2):

[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) não é suportado pelo Internet Explorer, como você pode ver nessa tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para ter maior compatibilidade, use [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
var array = [];

for (var propriedade in obj) {
  array.push(obj[propriedade ]);
}
console.log(array); // [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) é um método novo em JavaScript ainda não implementado em todos os browsers. Ele não existia portanto na altura do IE9.

Mas podes usar um polyfill assim:

```js
if (!Object.values) {
  Object.prototype.values = function(object) {
    var values = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(object);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      var k = keys[i];
      values.push(object[k]);
    }
    return values;
  }
}

var values = Object.values({
  foo: 'bar',
  fuji: 'baz'
});
console.log(values);
```